# how to solve missing positional argument in facebookauthprovider?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

i am using a github project to learn flutter and firebase , but i can figure out what the below 2 errors represent and how to solve them can someone please help

code :

```
try {
  final FacebookLoginResult facebookLoginResult =
  await fbLogin.logIn(['email']);
  if (facebookLoginResult.status == FacebookLoginStatus.loggedIn) {
    FacebookAccessToken facebookAccessToken =
        facebookLoginResult.accessToken;
    AuthCredential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.credential(
        accessToken: facebookAccessToken.token);
    User user = (await auth.signInWithCredential(credential)).user;
    print("signed in" + user.displayName);
    return user;
  }
```

Errors in Dart analysis tab :

> error: 1 positional argument(s) expected, but 0 found. (not_enough_positional_arguments at [flutter_app] lib\login_page.dart:32)

> error: The named parameter 'accessToken' isn't defined. (undefined_named_parameter at [flutter_app] lib\login_page.dart:33)

the issue is in this section of the code :

```
        AuthCredential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.credential(
        accessToken: facebookAccessToken.token);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are facing this error because `FacebookAuthProvider.credential()` does not taking any named parameter instead it takes a single positional argument `accessToken`.

Replace your line of code with this

```
AuthCredential credential = 
FacebookAuthProvider.credential(facebookAccessToken.token);
```